# Finding laplace inverse of $\frac{1}{(p+2)^2(p^2+\omega^2)}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

I am finding the laplace inverse of the below :-
$$\frac{1}{(p+2)^2(p^2+\omega^2)}$$

I can apply convolution theorem by taking $$f(p)=\frac{1}{(p+2)^2}, g(p)=\frac{1} 
{(p^2+\omega^2)}$$
and calculating the function which yield the above functions on laplace transform  i.e. essentially ,
$$F(t)=e^{-2t}t,G(t)=\frac{\sin{\omega}t}{\omega}$$
then solve by routine integration .

But this seems a little cumbersome . Is there a better way to solve the above ?

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse Laplace transformation is define as $f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi{i}}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}F(p)e^{pt}dp$, where integral is taken in the complex plane along some line $(a-i\infty,a+i\infty)$, where $a$ is some real number (greater than the real part of all singularities of $F(p)$)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform

We can close the contour, integrating along a part of the circle of big radius $R$.
Integral along this circle $\to0$ at $R\to\infty$  if $|F(p)|\to 0$ at $|p|\to\infty$ ; this is the case for $F(p)=\frac{1}{(p+2)^2(p^2+\omega^2)}$

[image]

$$f(t)=\oint_C=\frac{2\pi{i}}{2\pi{i}}\sum_{\text{all poles}}Res\frac{e^{pt}}{(p+2)^2(p^2+\omega^2)}=\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{2i\omega(2+i\omega)^2}+\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{-2i\omega(2-i\omega)^2}+\frac{d}{dp}\bigl(\frac{e^{pt}}{p^2+\omega^2}\bigr)|_{p=-2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\omega}\Im\frac{e^{i\omega t}}{(2+i\omega)^2}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{4+\omega^2}\bigl(t+\frac{4}{4+\omega^2}\bigr)$$
$$=\frac{(4-\omega^2)\sin \omega t-4\omega\cos\omega t}{\omega(4+\omega^2)^2}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{4+\omega^2}\bigl(t+\frac{4}{4+\omega^2}\bigr)$$

Please, check.

Comment: being a beginner in laplace and inverse laplace , i didn't knew this definition and this way of doing inverse laplace as taking contour and calculating residues . I solved it via partial fraction and it is the same as done by you. Thanks for answering !!

Comment: @llecxe Thank you - I'm please that it is useful. For me, this is strange that the straightforward method is not in the frontline when Laplace transform is studying. I saw this is a general approach. IMHO, so many problems could be solved more nicely, without using a boring mechanical routine... :)

Comment: Mind if i bother asking where to study complex analysis , any videos you recommend or any text you can share for getting the intution . I am from India and studying for a competitve examination and therefore a little short on time. I have my notes of complex analysis which i have solved but lacking confidence in the topic . Your thoughts ?

Comment: @llecxe  I was graduated as physicist from the uni in Novosibirsk long ago - I don't know whether those books (in Russian) were ever translated into English. But taken the modern books I like, for example, Mathematical method for physicist George B. Arfken  Hans J. Weber Frank E. Harris. Please look at part 20.7 Laplace transform 20.10 Inverse laplace transform. This is not a pure math book - it is designated to those who study physics and need to study essential math methods for problems solving.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Svyatoslav .means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use  [Partial Fraction Decomposition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\dfrac1{(p^2+w^2)(p+2)^2}=\dfrac a{p+2}+\dfrac b{(p+2)^2}+\dfrac{cp+d}{p^2+w^2}$$

Multiply both sides by $(p^2+w^2)(p+2)^2$

and  use the coefficients of different exponents of $p$ to find $a,b,c,d$

Finally use the  standard [formulae](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html)

Comment: sir ,any other trick apart from partial fractions ?

Comment: Sir ,suppose we have two polynomials $f(p)$ and $g(p)$ such that degree of $g(p)$ is greater than degree of $f(p)$. Suppose $g(p)$ has $n$ distinct factors . Can we always reduce the ratio $\frac{f(p)}{g(p)}$ into $\frac{A_1}{p-\alpha_1}+\frac{A_2}{p-\alpha_1}+\frac{A_3}{p-\alpha_1}...$ (something like we do in heaveside formula proof.)