# Find a function using a given Laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I don't have much experience with Laplace, In fact I've just been introduced to it, but I have a set of questions that ask me to find the function given the Laplace transformation:

[image]

I've also been given a list of Laplace transforms that we've been told will be frequently used:

[image]

What I'm not sure about is how to tackle the questions above. Is my answer going to be some combination of f(x)'s that I take from the list (e.g: cos(ax) + H(x-a) - x^n) or is there a separate method I should use?

I'm not asking for answers to all the questions since I want to be able to do them myself but feel free to use question (a) as an example to show the method and then I can attempt the rest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Continuing from Moo's comment, recall that the Laplace and inverse Laplace transforms are linear

Comment: Maybe this also be helpful - two methods of evaluation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074331/finding-laplace-inverse-of-frac1p22p2-omega2/4074419#4074419

Comment: @Moo Ok, I get what you've done but when you say to use the table for the inverse transform that confuses me a little bit. Nothing on the table has an F(p) that matches 1/4(p+1) , unless I'm meant to take e^-ax and adapt it so it works? Would that mean that the Laplace for 1/4(p+1) would be e^-4ax (since the denominator is multiplied by 4)? I'm still a bit confused

Comment: Ohhh, makes sense, therefore it would be 1/4 e^-x?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help